# Javascript calcul total in dynamically tab

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have short problem.

In my form I have multi-input and where the user change the values.

```
<div id="contenu">
  <h2>Renseigner ma fiche de frais du mois <?php echo $numMois."-".$numAnnee ?></h2>

  <form method="POST"  action="index.php?uc=gererFrais&action=validerMajFraisForfait">
  <div class="corpsForm">

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Eléments forfaitisés
        </legend>
<table width=100%>
        <tr>
        <td>Libelle</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Montant unitaire</td>
        <td>Montant total</td>
    </tr>
```

```
    ?>
<tr>
    <td width=20%><?php echo $libelle ?></td>
    <td width=20%><input type="text" id="<?php echo 'idFrais'.$incr; ?>" name="lesFrais[<?php echo $idFrais?>]"  size="10" min="0" autocomplete="off" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $quantite?>"  onkeyup="calculer(this)">
    <td width=20%><input type="text" id="<?php echo 'montant'.$incr; ?>" value="<?php echo $montant ?>" disabled></td>
    <td id='subtotal<?php echo $incr;?>' width=20%><?php echo $quantite*$montant; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php
          $incr ++;
        }
    ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">Total : </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

    </table>
      </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="piedForm">
  <p>
    <input id="ok" type="submit" value="Valider" size="20" />
    <input id="annuler" type="reset" value="Effacer" size="20" />
  </p> 
  </div>

  </form>
```

I want add one line where the total of the col "Montant total" has executed.

Exemple :
[image]

And the calcul has been executed direct, no refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all instead of using ID for subtotal use Class - `subtotal`. Then all you have to do is query all of those elements using

`querySelectorAll('.subtotal')` or `$('.subtotal')`

and store the resulting array (in jQuery a jQuery object like array) into a variable. Then add events to the quantity input fields and call a function which will iterate over all of the elements in the previously stored array and convert the text stored in them (which was generated using your `calculer` function) which can be accessed using

`subtotal[index].innerText`

and parse it into Number using

`Number(subtotal[index].innerText)`

and check if the resulting number is `NaN` (Not a Number) or not using `isNaN()` function. If not add to a local `total` variable and write the result in the end.

Hope this helps.

Here is the code -

```
function CalculateTotal(e) {
        var subtotal = querySelectorAll('.subtotal');
        var subtotalCount = subtotal.length;
        var subtotalValue;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < subtotalCount; i++) {
            subtotalValue = Number(subtotal[i].textContent);
            if (!isNaN(subtotalValue)) total += subtotal;
        }
        // Set the total element's textContent here.
}
```

Call the above function at the end of your `calculer` function.

Comment: for the moment i use this for calculate total of the line : <script>
function calculer(e){

 var i = e.getAttribute('id').length;
 var input_identifier = e.getAttribute('id').substring(i-1,i);
 var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal'+input_identifier)
 var quantity = e.value;
 var montant = document.getElementById('montant'+input_identifier);
 subtotal.textContent = ( parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(montant.value)).toFixed(2);

 return;

}
</script>

Comment: At the end of this function call another function which will do the work I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I don't arrived x) saddened I am novice in the Javascript

Comment: Why not? Please explain what you did.

Comment: I do not know how to implement him and am lacking time to look at the problem:s